# Macro to import entire text file into single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would need to create an Excel macro to import every single character from a txt file into a single cell in a column. E.g. if text is"test", then "t" would go to A1, "e" to A2, and so on in the spreadsheet. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please paste your code into the question so that we can help you work out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to adapt this to your needs:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim s As String, i As Long, j As Long
    Open "C:\TestFolder\Inputs.txt" For Input As #1 Len = 1
    i = 1
    j = 1

    Do Until EOF(1)
        s = Input(1, #1)
        Cells(i, j) = s
        i = i + 1
        If i > Rows.Count Then
            i = 1
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: @queens_living  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it worked opening a file with 758 579 characters and placing them in 758 579 excel rows! Wonderful!